# For PHP in chrome Incognito mode session variable ($this->session->userdata('logged_in');) is null

Tags: php, google-chrome, incognito-mode

```
 $getdata= $this->input->post();
```

$session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');
print_r("test1".json_encode($session_data));

Comment: Could you please show more code?

Comment: Can you describe your question?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remembering PHP Session Private Browsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30475878/remembering-php-session-private-browsing)

Comment: Hey guys, Thanks for your comments. I got the cause of this issue. This is because of chrome updates now chrome is not allowing to store third party cookies.

Answer (score 0):

The following are the steps to allow cookies for the xyz.com domain in the Chrome browser.

1. On your computer, open Chrome.
2. At the top right, click More(three vertical dots) > Settings.
3. Under 'Privacy and security', click Cookies and other site data.
4. Next to 'Sites that can always use cookies' click Add.
5. Enter the web address.
   [*.]xyz.com
6. Select Add.